# generating html report from soapui test results when running from maven & jenkins

Tags: junit, jenkins, soapui, test-report

I have a SOAPUI Project file with number of test suits. I have wrote a maven project to run that project file.
I am running that maven project (pom.xml) through jenkins.

As you can see in the pom.xml have enabled Junit Reporting and Print Report configurations.

I can get a simple test result/report like below.

[image]

[image]

[image]

My question is whether there is a plugin,tool or any other method to get a more visual, detailed test result report.preferably a html type report.

My pom.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>soapTest</groupId>
<artifactId>soapTest</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>Maven 2 SoapUI Sample</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>SmartBearPluginRepository</id>
        <url>http://www.soapui.org/repository/maven2/</url>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>eviwarePluginRepository</id>
        <url>http://www.eviware.com/repository/maven2/</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.smartbear.soapui</groupId>
            <artifactId>soapui-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.2</version>

            <configuration>
                <projectFile>soapui-project.xml</projectFile>
                <outputFolder>${project.build.directory}/reports</outputFolder>
                <junitReport>true</junitReport>
                <exportAll>true</exportAll>
                <printReport>true</printReport>
                <testSuite>Authenticate</testSuite>
            </configuration>

            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Hey, did you integrate Jenkins with SoapUI Open source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used maven sure fire report plugin and this question and the answer explains how i did it.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29671601/maven-sure-fire-plugin-report-empty

Answer (score -1):

You can define your reports via the commandline arguments of testrunner.  So for example if you want your report in HTML then just add -FHTML onto your runner

This is a Pro only feature though;

F : Sets the format of the report specified with the -R option, for Printable reports this is one of PDF, XLS, HTML, RTF, CSV, TXT, and XML. For Data Export this is either XML or CSV (SoapUI Pro only)

Full list of arguments here
http://www.soapui.org/test-automation/running-functional-tests.html

Comment: Thanx but i was looking for a non-pro option :)

Comment: Hey, did you integrate Jenkins with SoapUI Open source?

Answer (score -1):

Why settle for Junit report or any other report when we have plug and play utility for Generating Extent Report after soapui execution. Check this here https://github.com/iamakshayshar/SoapUI-Extentter

This is created by me and if anyone finds any issues in the plugin I am responsible to fix this.  It is simple plugin jar which we have to put in bin folder and an xml which we have to place in listener folder and we are good to go. Now any project in your soapui will generate Extent Report at the end of the execution. Project Level, TestSuite Level & TestCase Level.

Comment: Please do not post links to your work without clearly stating that the work is yours. You should read https://sqa.stackexchange.com/help/promotion for more information, then edit your answer.

Comment: I ditto what Kate said. Also, this is essentially a "link only" answer, which tends to be flagged and deleted. Links go stale over time. Can you explain more about this option? Can you include some example code?

Comment: Thank you @KatePaulk. Edited the answer. That is my work and I own the plugin.

Comment: @LeeJensen sure I understand. I own the plugin and all the details are on Github readme page. 
It is simple plugin jar which we have to put in bin folder and an xml which we have to place in listener folder and we are good to go. Now any project in your soapui will generate Extent Report at the end of the execution. Project Level, TestSuite Level & TestCase Level.